# How bad could $\|A^k\|$ be when $\rho(A) < 1-\delta$

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, operator-norms

(Sorry, I do hate editing this many many times but let me try the last time)

Gelfand's formula says that

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \|A^k\|^{1/k} = \rho(A)$$

I am wondering whether there is any way to make this non-asymptotic. for example, I would like to have a set $S$ of matrices so that for any matrix $A\in S$, $\|A^k\|$ goes to 0 with some exponential rate. (A candidate might be, for any matrix $A$ with $\rho(A) < 1/2$ and $\|A\|\le T$, $\|A^k\| \le T^{100}(2/3)^k$. Although I haven't thought through whether there is any trivial counterexample for this statement. )

Comment: Consider $\binom{1/2\;x}{0\;1/2}$. It has spectral radius $1/2$ and operator norm $\ge|x|$. Now put $k=1$ and $x$ as large as you like ...

Comment: To amplify on the previous comment by @SebastianGoette: replace the $1/2$ in his example by $0.$

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thanks! yeah I kind of thought such counter-examples. but this cases have a simple fix -- the frobenius norm of the matrix is bounded. So my point here is not to find a counter example but I'd like to get some constructive theory that really rule out the bad instances.

Comment: @IgorRivin Please see my edit of the question and my comments to Sebastian. I would really like to get something constructive here..

Comment: Alex, I think that you need to figure out what you actually want to prove, rather than continually adding extra conditions every time someone points out a counterexample

Comment: Sebastian's example also refutes your latest version since $\|A^k\|\sim k \|A\|\rho(A)^k$. As Yemon pointed out, it really can't work very well if your question + edits is a livestream of your thought process. Please try to think it through before you go public.

Comment: [This](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/jjg/en/mathematics/thesis/) may be of interest (Section 3.3 in particular).

Comment: @StefanKohl: I was referring to this question and its predecessor: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222205/quantitive-version-of-gelfand-formula#comment548428_222205

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Ah, I see -- there was some history ... . I remove my comment.

Comment: @IgorRivin You probably overshot this: if A=[[0 x][0 0]] then $A^2=0$.

Comment: @FanZheng The OP wanted just ONE $k.$ $k=1$ is fine in that case.

Comment: @ChristianRemling,  Thanks for all your comments. I guess it's not clear what I want to prove and that's the beauty of its right? I just wanted to have something to bound about $\|A^k\|$ in terms of $\rho(A)^k$ weakly. For example, if $\rho(A) < 1/2$, can you say $\|A^k\| \le ||A||^{100} (2/3)^k$. I am looking for the correct theorem to be proved here -- so what's the right bound is just my question probably. Thanks!

Comment: @YemonChoi, Thanks for the comments. Please see my reply to Christian as well. I mainly just wanted to control $\|A^k\|$ in a non-asymptotic way. In other words, I'd like to have some version of non-asymptotic Gelfand's formula.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a moving target and does not seem to show signs of enough thought before asking

Comment: @YemonChoi, alright .. You don't seem to like open-ended question..

Comment: @AlexWenxinXu That is because MathOverflow is **not meant for open-ended questions**, and not meant as some kind of discussion forum for evolving conversations

Comment: @YemonChoi, I see. Sorry I am very new to this forum.. I guess all I should expect is that the question in my mind  is indeed an open question and I didn't miss any common knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To get a hang of the behaviour of matrix powers, you should consider powers of Jordan blocks:
$$
J_k(\lambda)^n = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2}\lambda^{n-2} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-1}\lambda^{n-k+1} \\
 & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-2}\lambda^{n-k+2} \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &  & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  & &  & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\\
 &  &  &  &  & \lambda^n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
From this case, you can generalize to see what happens if you vary the magnitude of the off-diagonal entries
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & \mu &  \\
 & \lambda & \mu & \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots \\
 &  & & \ddots & \ddots \\
 &  & &  & \lambda & \mu\\
 &  &  &  &  & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}^n
 = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\mu & \binom{n}{2}\lambda^{n-2}\mu^2 & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-1}\lambda^{n-k+1}\mu^{k-1} \\
 & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\mu & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-2}\lambda^{n-k+2}\mu^{k-2} \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &  & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  & &  & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\mu\\
 &  &  &  &  & \lambda^n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
As you can see, the off-diagonal elements can grow arbitrarily before the exponential convergence kicks in. You can generalize further to cases in which the $\mu$ terms are in a different diagonal (the trick to get these expansions is always using the binomial theorem on $(\lambda I + \mu Z)^n$, where $Z$ contains the desired diagonal).

If, instead of an exact Jordan block, you have bounds on the magnitude of diagonal and off-diagonal entries, you can turn these identities into estimates.

Once you leave the realm of nonnormal matrices (for which $||A^n||=||A||^n$), this is what is going to happen in general. The Schur factorization tells you that every matrix is essentially triangular (up to an orthogonal factor which does not affect norms), so the only possible bounds that I can foresee are the ones that are derived from the above technique.

To get something more tame, you could try restricting to sets of matrices for which the off-diagonal part of the Schur factorization is small with respect to its diagonal (small "distance from normality"). If I recall correctly, there is some discussion of this phenomenon of growth of powers of nonnormal matrices in the famous paper [nineteen dubious ways to compute the matrix exponential](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S00361445024180?journalCode=siread), but at the moment I can't get behind the SIAM paywall.